# mysql merge rows if id = the same

Tags: mysql, database, merge, row

I have about 20 entires (rows) in my db with matching id's, is there any query I can do that will merge the rows if the id is the same?

luckily there is no chance that a cell will replace each other, they will simply need to merge.

eg..

```
id    c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7    c8    c9    c10

3     1
3           4           3
```

Comment: I can think of a few programmatic approaches - are you using this data in an application?  If so, what language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to group using any grouping function

```
select  id,max(c1) as c1,max(c2) as c2,max(c3) as c3,...
from    [Table]
group by Id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select group_concat(c1), group_concat(c2) ....
```